# Automated 1D Linear Interpolation

Tags: vb.net, linear-interpolation, math.net

I'm importing a curve per points from a Datagridview. In order to correct this curve with an algorythm, I have to rebuild it, to have a larger number of points. To do this I have to use a 1D linear interpolation calculus. In order to make this process automatically, when I wrote this algorhytm in MATLAB, I used the `interp1` command. Is there a corresponding command in VB.net? Thanks in advance. Best regards.

---

**Edit:** Does anyone know how Math.NET Linear Interpolation works? I've found their guide on how to use this command but I'm not able to make this working.

Comment: [Matlab's interp1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) supports several different interpolation methods. Did you use the default method (piecewise linear interpolation) or something else?

Comment: @PascalGetreuer thanks for your answer. I've used the default one, so the linear. I'm trying to find a corresponding command on vb.net on different libraries - such as Math.NET or Accord - without understanding how to use this commands. In MATLAB I've typed three different arrays as input and my code is written as:
y-interpolated=interp1(x-native,y-native,x-interpolated)